# Force ViewController in UITabBarController to be landscape in iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, rotation, landscape, uiinterfaceorientation

Ok, I am getting really desperate on it, trying every possibility but always ending up in the same (frustrating ) place.

My setup is quite simple, I have an iPad application that uses a UITabBarController that I set up with storyboards.

The first item can rotate as much as it wants, I don't care, I configured it in Autolayout so everything is fine when the device is rotated.

My real problem comes in with the second item, which I need to be displayed only(!) in landscape, from the beginning. I read all the documentation and similar questions of Stackoverflow but I am still failing to achieve this.

My latest try, which should be working according to my current understanding was the following:

I learned that the solution of the problem will somehow involve these three methods of UIViewController `-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations`, `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` and `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate`. However, as I am presenting my view controllers in UITabBarController, these don't even get called on the actual view controllers but rather on its parent, the UITabBarController. So, I subclassed UITabBarController and added the following code to it to let my view controllers be able to decide by themselves how they wont to rotate:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return [self.selectedViewController supportedInterfaceOrientations];
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return [self.selectedViewController preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return [self.selectedViewController shouldAutorotate];
}
```

In the debugger, I can see that this actually works and these methods finally get called on my actual view controllers.

Now, I need to implemented these in my second view controller that I want to be displayed only in landscape, so that it can control its rotation behaviour by itself. I think I have now tried almost every possible combination of return values in these three methods. The closest I got was actually that the view controller would keep its orientation, when it has been initially opened in landscape.

My biggest problem is when the view is opened in portrait, I dan't figure out how I can force the view controller to set its orientation to landscape, even though the device is in portrait. I am really starting to wonder whether there actually is a clean way to do this! According to my understanding, this clean way should have been using the `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation`, as the documentation for it states:

> If the view controller supports multiple orientations but appears better in a different orientation, you can provide a preferred orientation by overriding the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation method.

This seems to be like the exact solution of my problem, so according to my understanding, this code should work:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

But it doesn't! And the reason is than when initially presented, `- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation` is not even called (neither on the parent UITabBarController nor on the actual view controller that uses the above return values).

Can someone explain where I am thinking wrong in this? What am I missing here?

Btw, I also tried hacks like putting `[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];` into `viewDidLoad` or `viewWillAppear:` but neither of them worked as well... I am getting very frustrated on this!

Comment: Same here, I tried everything you mentioned and the same result!! Did you figure out how to do it?? It will help me a lot. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

If your `UITabBarController` is the RootViewController then the orientation management should be done inside your `UITabBarController` not it's children.

You should alway manage orientation changes in the parent not the children.

In your `UITabBarController` should autorotate to user interface check which view controller is currently displayed and return `YES`/`NO` correspondingly

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! With the approach to subclass `UITabBarController` I am letting the parent manage rotations, but I have the advantage to be able to treat special cases in subclasses, as I want to do here. So, this would result in the same thing that you are suggesting where the root checks who is currently displayed and then manages rotation according to that. My problem is that initially the view is always in portait, so I have no way to tell the view controller in the beginning that it should show itself in landscpape (even though the device might be in portrait.)